# Firebase Authentication: Email verification flow

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I managed to setup firebase authentication flow (signInWithCredentials) and then an email verification on my react app. The sign in flow has no problem at all and then as for the verification, I suppose it works since the verification-action link redirects the user to the continue URL I have set- to input the email to be verified, I get an emailVerified=true; on the email account and it stays signed-in after the verify-action flow.
However, the problem I noticed is that, going back to sign-in, the email/ password for a verified account apparently throws a 400 Bad Request:

`accounts:signInWithPassword 400 (Bad Request) _signInWithCredential @ credential.ts:37 signInWithEmailAndPassword @ email_and_password.ts:351`

that just signifies the signInWithCredentials do not work anymore... any idea what or why that is?

PS: I have looked through my console and relevant docs to see if there is a provision to explain or work around this.. couldn't find anything.

SignInWithCredentials: Email and Password expected to sign in as usual